# wso2 apim 1.10.0 SSL communication

Tags: ssl, wso2, api-manager

I am trying to call a WSO2 API through https port 8243. However, when I make a call, the client app (web app) gets a 502 bad gateway error (which is logged inside WSO2 apim server carbon log file).

I see the exception below.

Please Note that, I have received a CA signed cert inside a jks from my networking team... I imported It through management console into keystore... I can view the company certs as well from the console:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-12-19 16:51:12,890] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  
I/O error: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} 
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

Comment: Are you trying to call HTTPS endpoint from API Manager?

Comment: @Rans ..yes..I am trying to invoke the api using https on port 8243.

Comment: I am calling https end point from another web application.

Comment: My question is about the endpoint which is configured in the API Manager. According to the error log, it seems you are getting the SSL Exception in API Manager side.  So I expect that you are using an HTTPS endpoint inside the API which is configured in API Manager.

Comment: The end point is http...I am load balancing two server nodes

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do and where the error happens. If you are trying to update the certificate of API Manager, importing the certificate to existing keystore will not work. Please have a look at the documentation on creating a keystore with a CA signed certificate. https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Creating+New+Keystores

Comment: Thx for sharing this link..however, I have already gone through this. As earlier confirmed..I am using a http endpoint inside the API which is configured in API Manager. Do you think that is an issue? Why can't I use a http end point? I am only trying to understand why I receive this error when my API is invoked through https. And yes, the "unknown_ca" error happens in wso2 api manager log file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185563/discussion-between-rans-and-kishore-paila).

Comment: Thanks Rans. My issue is resolved now.

Comment: Great. Added the summery as an answer in case if anyone else faces a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to update the certificate of API Manager, importing the certificate to existing keystore will not work.

Please have a look at the documentation[1] on creating a keystore with a CA signed certificate when you create the new keystore with updated certificate.

The main keystore of WSO2 products is *wso2carbon.jks* file which holds private certificate entry. When you update the certificate with keystore you have to update all the configuration files listed in documentation[2] to refer to new keystore file and also you will have to update related properties(i.e: keystore password, key password, alias).

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Creating+New+Keystores

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon443/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products